# Inserting date in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I try to execute this query

```
INSERT  INTO StateRegion
        ( FullName ,
          Abbreviation ,
          RegionType ,
          Admitted ,
          Capital
        )
VALUES  ( 'Alabama' ,
          'AL' ,
          1 ,
          '1819-Dec-14' ,
          'Montgomery'
        );
```

it gives me error sql date conversion error :

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string

Admitted is a Date type.

The issue is I can not change this format : `1819-Dec-14`, is it possible to add convert method to the query above ?

Table definition :

```
CREATE TABLE StateRegion
(
  ID            bigint       PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
  FullName      varchar(50)  NOT NULL,
  Abbreviation  varchar(2)   NOT NULL,
  RegionType    smallint     NOT NULL,
  Admitted      date         NULL,
  Capital       varchar(50)  NULL
);
```

Comment: Has this ever worked, or did it just stop working?

Comment: It did not work, the line was not inserted

Comment: @Souregi You can Use cast as Date as i Updated

Comment: What is the table definition and the default language of the login?

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar : cast did not work

Comment: @Martin Smith : Default language is french

Comment: @Souregi its working http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2720/1

Comment: Well Dec isn't a valid French month name. Can you change the default language of the login or issue a `set language english`?

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar txs for help , the problem was the default langage :
INSERT INTO StateRegion (FullName, Abbreviation, RegionType, Admitted, Capital) VALUES
  ('Alabama', 'AL', 1, CAST('1819-Déc-14' as DATE), 'Montgomery'); 
This one worked for me

Comment: @MartinSmith Ohh... Great

Comment: @Souregi So, you couldn't change the format, but you could change how to write `Dec`?

Comment: @Lamak When Martin Smith answered before edit and it worked for me with **Déc**, i tought of : set language english

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The month name part of that date format is interpreted according to the language of the login.

You can change the default language of the login to US English or British English if you must work with that format or issue a

```
  Set language english
```

To set the format at run time before the problematic query then optionally switch it back afterwards.

If you have the choice using yyyy-mm-dd or yyyymmdd would be preferable formats for date literals though that both avoid this issue when casting to `date`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a parameterized query.  Parameterization will send the date to the server in binary, avoiding any string conversions which depend upon the client locale.

Example in C#:

```
SqlCommand sqc = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO MyTable (DateColumn) VALUES (@date)", con);
sqc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", new DateTime(1819, 12, 14));
```

If you are running this from an interactive batch (SQL Server Management Studio, or similar), use `SET LANGUAGE` to ensure the dates are parsed correctly:

```
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;

INSERT INTO StateRegion (FullName, Abbreviation, RegionType, Admitted, Capital)
VALUES ('Alabama', 'AL', 1, '1819-Dec-14', 'Montgomery');
```

[SqlFiddle example showing correct parsing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/95c81/3)

Comment: The question isn't tagged with C#, why giving a solution using it?

Comment: @Lamak, because it is the most common client for SQL Server if it is not being done through an interactive UI.

Answer (score 0):

Do not confuse storage format and display format.  Just because the server store the date in the database as '1819-12-14' you can use a custom formatting output for the display.
Then correct for the display issue with a function such as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION usp_FormatedDateString (@Date Date)
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RETURN AS VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @I INT = 0
    DECLARE @M AS VARCHAR(100) = 'JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC'
    SET @RETURN = CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,@Date) AS VARCHAR(4)) 
    SET @I = DATEPART(MONTH, @Date) - 1
    SET @RETURN = @RETURN + '-' + SUBSTRING(@M,(@I*3)+1,3)+'-'+ CAST (DATEPART(DAY,@Date) AS VARCHAR(2))
    RETURN @RETURN
END
GO
```

Then when you display the results:

```
SELECT FullName,Abbreviation,RegionType, dbo.usp_FormatedDateString (Admitted) as Admitted, Capital FROM StateRegion
```

It will display correct and store correctly.

Answer (score -2):

You can try to use an explicit format for the conversion. You are not explaining **why** you can't change the format, but I imagine that you are reading the values somehow that are already stored as that. You can use `CONVERT`:

```
DECLARE @Admitted VARCHAR(11);
SET @Admitted = '1819-Dec-14'


SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,RIGHT(@Admitted,2)+' '+
                        SUBSTRING(@Admitted,6,3)+' '+
                        LEFT(@Admitted,4),106);
```

Answer (score -3):

Chang datatype of date to VARCHAR